# still Unable to start the daemon process

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm, daemon

I know this question has been asked before but i have tried:
- deleting the gradle and restarting android after invalidating cache
- also running android studio as an administrator.
- Replacing "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m" with "org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m"
  but still getting the same error

> unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by
>   incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized
>   jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide chapter on the
>   daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/4.4/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
>
> ### Please read the following process output to find out more:

this problem started after I renamed my generated apk before deleting it. Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is your android-studio located in /opt folder?

Comment: I'm using windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

I believe I may have had a similar issue, the issue I had was caused by me adjusting `command line options` in `settings` under `Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler` and spelling something incorrectly.

One way to check if this is the case is to compile the project manually via the terminal. This is done by typing `gradlew clean` and/or `gradlew build` into the terminal.

If it works, then that's your issue.

Comment: thanks for your help but, It seemed to start working after i restarted my system.